# Delete embedded string

Tags: java, string

I'm looking for the most efficient Java method that would allow me to 'delete an embedded string'. For example, if i had the string `"Bob said \"Hello world!\"."`, and I call the method on it, the result should be: `"Bob said ."`. Help would be appreciated!

Note that I want this method to be **general**, so that if Bob says something besides "hello world" it would still work.

Comment: Are you looking for any embedded string or just "Hello world!" ?

Comment: The method could return a string. And yes, any embedded string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
String string = "Bob said \"Hello world!\".";
string = string.replaceAll("\"[^\"]+\"", "");
```

Use replaceFirst if you only want to remove the first quoted text.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regex:

```
String newString = string.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to accomplish this.

```
    private String removeSubStrings(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("\"[^\"]*\"", "");
    }
```

Calling removeSubStrings("Bob said \"Hello world!\".") will yield `Bob said .`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an even number of `\"`s in the string, you can use something like this:

```
private String deleteEmbedded(String input) {
    String[] split = input.split("\"");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i+=2) {
        sb.append(split[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```